# My code not working on server but working on localhost

Tags: javascript

[Code not working on server want to find geo-location and store into database](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)

> code not working on server want to find geo-location and store into a database it working properly on localhost its [w3school code.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  window.location = "position/?latitude="+position.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What type of error are you getting on the server? Is it not showing anything? Is it showing something wrong? Or is the result not what you were expecting?

Comment: actually i am also not getting same code working localhost but when i put on server it not working.

Comment: I understand that it's not working on the server, but it is hard to help you unless you tell us what is happening. What do you mean by not working? Also, maybe a better description of this "server". I suggest you edit your question with more details.

Comment: Could be a permission thing. Have you granted the site permission to access your location in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

There is no geolocation library on the server. `navigator.geolocation` only exists in the browwer.